# How do I inform my form that a payment has been made?

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

I have a form with several fields including a PayPal digital goods button.  When the user clicks on the PayPal button he gets taken out of the website's workflow to a pop-up window.  After remitting payment the return URL also opens in the same pop-up window.

So, how would I inform my form that the payment has been made?  I would like to put in a green check mark in the form as visual cue for the user and perhaps insert the PayPal transaction ID as a hidden field (or maybe I should save that in the session).

Comment: I don't know why the post was down voted.  Did I break a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digital goods code inserts an iframe in the parent page. The return URL opens as an overlay from that iframe.

I chose to save the information returned by paypal in a session. Then from inside the iframe I execute a JavaScript function that's located in the parent page like so:
`window.parent.paypal();`  Inside the paypal function I remove the iframe from the DOM and I insert the necessary visual cues to alert the customer that payment has been remitted.

Comment: Interesting approach.  Normally when sending people off to a paysite, you redirect the entire browser session and let that site redirect back to yours.

Comment: I need to keep the user on the site. *Requirement